# Program to display whether the user entered data is a letter or a number

Tags: c

I wrote the following code in C. This code helps us to find whether the user entered character is a letter or a number

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    char a[26];
    a[0]='a';
    a[1]='b';
    a[2]='c';
    a[3]='d';
    a[4]='e';
    a[5]='f';
    a[6]='g';
    a[7]='h';
    a[8]='i';
    a[9]='j';
    a[10]='k';
    a[11]='l';
    a[12]='m';
    a[13]='n';
    a[14]='o';
    a[15]='p';
    a[16]='q';
    a[17]='r';
    a[18]='s';
    a[19]='t';
    a[20]='u';
    a[21]='v';
    a[22]='w';
    a[23]='x';
    a[24]='y';
    a[25]='z';


    char b[10];
    b[0]='0';
    b[1]='1';
    b[2]='2';
    b[3]='3';
    b[4]='4';
    b[5]='5';
    b[6]='6';
    b[7]='7';
    b[8]='8';
    b[9]='9';
    printf("Enter the character of your choice-");
    char c[1];
    scanf("%c",&c);
    int i =0;
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
       if (c==a[i])
            printf("The character is an alphabet");
    }
    int j;

    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
       if (c==b[j])
            printf("The character is an number");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code seems fine to me but it is not working. Please help. I get an error as -
comparison between pointer and integer. Also are the letters entered by me in the array get stored as - [a,b,c,d....] or as abcd....

Comment: I dont know if this is the way you have to do it but there is a much easier way. Look into the ASCII table. ASCII is a table that converts integers to characters and vice versa. aka `'a' = 97`. Therefore if we want to know if a character is a letter we can just test if is in between 'a' and 'z' in ascii and if it is then it is a lower case letter.

Comment: is there any more convenient way of adding elements to a character array as compared to what i did?

Comment: @xing can you please explain 'char b[11] ="0123456789"?

Comment: @xing please explain a[27] = "abcd...xyz" and what do you mean by it?

Comment: you mean to say i don't need to write a[0]='a' a[1]='b' seperately and writing a[27]='abcdef.....' is sufficient?

Comment: i removed a[0]='a' a[1]='b'... and in place of that i added a[27]="abcde...."? But my code doesn't work now?

Comment: The entire alphabet . can you provide the code in a seperate answer? it is really difficult to understand it in this way

Comment: You need to learn from a book about initializing arrays of characters, and about strings.  Your code could also use `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` from the `<ctype.h>` header for compactness.  If you make `a` and `b` into null-terminated strings (as suggested by @xing), then you can use `<strchr()` from `<string.h>` to find the character (or not) in the arrays.  Note, too, that letter refers to a single character in an alphabet, and alphabet refers to multiple characters.  And you'd probably be better of using the term digit rather than number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change :

```
char c[1]
```

to :

```
char c
```

as `char c[1]` indicates an array of one `char` but what you want is a `char`.

Otherwise, you should use the array like this :

```
char c[1];
scanf("%c", c);
```

(as `scanf` takes a pointer as argument and in this case `c` is already a pointer, since it as actually an address) and then change the condition :

```
if (c==a[i])
```

to :

```
if (c[0] == a[i])
```

to be accurate.

Comment: is there any more convenient way of adding elements to a character array as compared to what i did?

Comment: @Marievi The original code corresponds to `char a[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // using as an array of chars, not a NUL-terminated string`. It a string was wanted, it should be declared as `char s[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`, which of course would have an array size of 27.

Comment: @TomBlodget yes it was a typo! Will re-comment, thanks!

Comment: @jamesgem you can use : int i; char ch = 'a'; for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) { a[i] = ch; ch = ch + 1; } or char a[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

Answer (score 1):

In my mind, a better way to detect character type is compare a first and last character in ascii.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;

    printf("Enter the character of your choice: ");
    scanf("%c", &c);

    if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        printf("The character is an alphabet");
    }
    else if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        printf("The character is an number");
    }
    else {
        printf("The character is not valid");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for my language.

Comment: What if `scanf()` fails?

Comment: This way is a lot cleaner but isn't extensible to different sets of letters, such as `"AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZzÆæØøÅå"`.

Comment: BTW—The character set is the execution charset that the compiler is told to compile for, which is almost certainly not ASCII.